# Display value in texteditor tinymce on click of combo box:Yii 1.1

Tags: javascript, yii, tinymce

I have to use text editor i.e. tinymce in my form .I have to show data in text editor on selection of combo box.Simply using textarea there is no problem i could get value in my text area on selection of combo.Now i have to use text editor instead of simple textarea.
My code for view is :

```
<div class="row col2">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'template'); ?>

<?php 
        $records = CHtml::listData(EmailTemplate::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'email_template_id','condition'=>"status= '1'")), 'email_template_id', 'subject');
        // echo $form->dropDownList($model,'template',$records,array('id'=>'myDropDown','empty' => 'Select'));

            echo $form->dropDownList($model,'template',$records,array(
                                  'id' => 'myDropDown',
                                  'empty' => 'Select Template',
                                  'ajax' => array(
                                  'type'=>'POST',
                                  'url'=>CController::createUrl('reply/description'),//your controller and action name
                                  'update'=>'#myTextArea', 
                                  'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                    $("#myTextArea").empty(); 
                                    $("#myTextArea").val(data); 

                                  } '
                                  ))); 
            ?>

<?php echo $form->error($model,'template'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row col2">
          <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
          <?php echo                $form->textArea($model,'message',array('id'=>'myTextArea','style'=>'width: 680px; height: 300px;')); ?>
          <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
      </div>
```

My js code is as follows:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#myTextArea",
    theme: "modern",
    preformatted:true,
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
   plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   menubar:false,

    toolbar: "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent| forecolor backcolor",

 }); 

 </script>
<script>
$('#myDropDown').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('reply/description'); ?>",
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {dropDownValue: $(this).val()},
        success: function(template, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
            $('#myTextArea').val(data);
        }‌
    });
});
 </script>
```

My controller is:

```
 public function actionDescription()
{   
    $cvId=0;
    $cvId= $_POST['Reply']['template'];
      if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
          if($cvId>0){
        $templateModel=EmailTemplate::model()->findByPk($cvId);
        echo $templateModel->description;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question here or any indication of a specific problem. Also no indication of any `tinymce` related code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured out answer for my question.simple change was made in dropdownlist code.It works well now.

```
<?php 
$records = CHtml::listData(EmailTemplate::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'email_template_id','condition'=>"status= '1'")), 'email_template_id', 'subject');
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'template',$records,array(
                                  'id' => 'myDropDown',
                                  'empty' => 'Select Template',
                                  'ajax' => array(
                                  'type'=>'POST',
                                  'url'=>CController::createUrl('marketingEmail/description'),
                                  'update'=>'#myTextArea', 
                                  'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                    $("#myTextArea").empty(); 
                                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data); 

                                  } '
                                  ))); 
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once TinyMCE appears on the page simply changing the content of the underlying textarea (are you are doing in your AJAX call) won't cause TinyMCE to reload the content.

You need to use TinyMCE's APIs to set the content of the editor in your success method of your AJAX call.

For example:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);
```

...where data is a string containing the content that is returned by your AJAX call.